# Strange for loops I'm not familiar with: "for (id * in *)"

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, fast-enumeration

I apologize if this question is exceedingly simple, but I've Googled like crazy and am unable to find a suitable explanation for what this is.

```
for (id line in self.lines){
    [linesCopy addObject:[line copyWithZone:zone]];
}
```

I'm just learning Objective-C, and this is a form of `for` loop that I've never seen before. I'm familiar with the simple

```
for (int x = 1, x < 10, x++)
```

style of `for` loop.

Comment: google "fast enumeration"

Comment: Wow, the competition for the right answer was amazingly fierce on this one!

Comment: This is why everybody should read tutorials.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [*Cocoa Core Competencies*: Enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Enumeration.html):

> ### Fast Enumeration
>
> Several Cocoa classes, including the collection classes, adopt the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol. You use it to retrieve elements held by an instance using a syntax similar to that of a standard C for loop, as illustrated in the following example:
>
> ```
> NSArray *anArray = // get an array;
> for (id element in anArray) {
>     /* code that acts on the element */
> }
> ```
>
> As the name suggests, fast enumeration is more efficient than other forms of enumeration.

In case you didn't know, `id` is an Objective-C type that basically means “a pointer to any Objective-C object”.  Note that the pointer-ness of `id` is built in to it; you usually do **not** want to say `id *`.

If you expect the elements of `anArray` to be of a specific class, say `MyObject`, you can use that instead:

```
for (MyObject *element in anArray) {
    /* code that acts on the element */
}
```

However, neither the compiler nor the runtime will check that the elements are indeed instances of `MyObject`.  If an element of `anArray` is **not** an instance of `MyObject`, you'll probably end up trying to send it a message it doesn't understand, and get a selector-not-recognized exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a `forin` loop, also called fast enumeration. Basically, the syntax is:

```
for (SomeObjectIAmExpecting *localVariableName in anArrayOfObjects)
{
    if (![localVariableName isKindOfClass:[SomeObjectIAmExpecting class]]) continue; //To avoid errors.
     //do something to them
}
```

Comment: How about:     for (Class *object in collection)

Comment: Thanks! This is one of those things that had impossible-to-search-precisely keywords in it. Does the expected object have to be (or be castable to) the same type of object as those in the array?

Comment: @RobertHall No, but remember that it will be whatever it is. If you are expecting an `NSString` and you get an `NSNumber`, you obviously won't be able to get the `length` of it. Because of this, you sometimes have to check the class. See edit.

Comment: @Undo Why use `if (!(foo == bar))` instead of `if (foo != bar)`? Same result but unusual to what you are doing.

Comment: @rmaddy Because I did it an odd way - it's done the 'normal person' way now.

Comment: @Undo It would probably be better to check each element's class using `isKindOfClass:` to allow for subclasses.  It would also probably be a better example if it used `continue` instead of `return` when the element's class doesn't match.

Comment: @robmayoff Why `continue`?

Comment: I might ask, why `return`?  Using `return` makes the loop process all elements of the array up to the first non-passing element, and ignore the remaining elements.  In my experience, this is not a common pattern.  The common patterns are (1) finding the first element that passes the test and processing it only, and (2) processing all elements that pass (or fail) the test, regardless of position in the array.  The common patterns use `continue`.

Comment: @robmayoff WOW! I didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Congratulations on your WWDC scholarship.  Perhaps I will see you there!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30522/discussion-between-undo-and-rob-mayoff)

Comment: @robmayoff http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30522/discussion-between-undo-and-rob-mayoff

Comment: @stephsharp Ohhh... I worked hard on making that code bold :)

Comment: @Undo Oh, sorry! It looked a bit strange with the first line in a separate block of code to the rest of the for loop.

Comment: @StephSharp Yep - your edit improved the post. [I approved it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2283647). Thanks!

Comment: @robmayoff You here at WWDC?

Answer (score 1):

It's the shorthand equivalent of this common form:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.lines count]; i++) {
    id line = [self.lines objectAtIndex:i];
    // ...
}
```

It's such a common looping idiom (walking through some collection, array, set, etc. an item at a time), that it's been turned into a shorthand form like this, called "fast enumeration".

In fact, in its internal implementation, it's actually slightly more faster than doing it yourself, so it's preferable both for clarity and performance.

Comment: It uses neither the `count` nor the `objectAtIndex:` messages.

Comment: @robmayoff Obviously not; I didn't claim it did. But this is the common form that it replaces, and the OP is new to ObjC syntax.

Comment: Maybe "equivalent" is a strong word here - for one, you can fast enumerate over a set, which does not even implement `objectAtIndex:`, so in my book they are not "equivalent". But agreed, we are getting into details.

Answer (score 1):

It's a statement that can be used with classes that are conform to [`NSFastEnumeration`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) protocol. When you have this available, the Objective-C programming guide suggest you to use it. Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH7-SW30). It's a way to iterate over a collection without the traditional `for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)` syntax.

Mind that it doesn't usually support deleting and inserting elements while iterating through this way (also by using normal `for` loops you should take care about indices in any case).

Basically all standard collections supports this way of iteration.